# Starting httpd - Error retrieving pid file (null)

Tags: linux, fedora, apache

I manually compiled and installed `httpd` on Fedora. I am trying to start it for the first time:

```
./apachectl start -d ../
```

and receive the following error:

```
(20014)Internal error: Error retrieving pid file (null)
 Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try running it with sudo?

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the **httpd.pid** file and restart apache or xampp to solve this issue.
Following page explains the instructions to remove that file:

[Removing the httpd.pid file](http://questionfriends.com/questions/4fbfb8ce1c657/20014internal-error-error-retrieving-pid-file-logshttpd.pid)

Comment: classic case of why you shouldn't link to external answers... this page no longer exists

Answer (score 4):

I face same problem in ubuntu, and I try to run this code.
Try to run :

```
sudo rm /opt/lampp/httpd.pid
```

then

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 1):

A pid file is a file that contains the process id of a daemon (either in the file body or the file name).  It is used by a daemon to make sure only one version of it is running at one time.  It does this by either checking for the pid files existence or using the flock feature of some os/filesystems to lock it.

The error indicates that it could not access the pid file, which would indicate to my a permissions error.

Comment: I recursively set the permissions on the folder to 755. Still same error.

Comment: run it with strace, it will show which pid file it is trying to open (or what it is trying to do that is failing)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `(13)Permission denied:` so just add "sudo " and then add your commend.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on termux.
i did

```
su
find -iname httpd.pin
```

and then

```
su
rm /sbin/.magisk/mirror/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid
```